# How can I query for documents in specific date range?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I want to get all records within specified date range like this:

```
@docs = Document.where(:created_at => {'$gte' => Time.now.midnight, '$lt' => Time.now.midnight + 24.hours})
```

But the result of thiq query are array of documents with created_at >= Time.now.midnight, the second part of condition for created_at field is not applied.
Even with UTC format like Time.now.midnight.utc I get the same result.
If I`ll change condition for

```
:created_at like {'$lt' => Time.now.midnight + 24.hours, '$gte' => Time.now.midnight}
```

then I`ll get all documents with created_at < Time.now.midnight + 24.hours, second condition is not applied to query here too.

Answer (score 0):

This is issue in mongoid, fixed on master now (https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/commit/f326de5acc969e1342e640dc026de7e94bf4cf49#lib/mongoid/matchers.rb). Last version with this issue tested - 2.0.1